# Left swipe for delete and edit,delete

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am not able to find a way around this. Is it possible to have delete option using left swipe and also using edit and delete.

I have edit button on the left of the navigation bar.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

and commitEditingStyle method as below

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
//delete code here
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
```

}

After using this, the left swipe is not being detected at all. the only way to delete seems to be by going to the edit mode and deleting from there.
help would be appreciated.

I am a newbie so please go easy with me :)

Comment: Yes. Other than no delete code in what you posted, what seems to be the problem.

Comment: Now the left swipe is not detected at all. I can delete by going to edit mode and deleting there..but not using the left swipe :(

Comment: BTW: You should only use an EditButton on the left side of the NavigationBar if you don't use an UINavigationController. Either way, it's always better to stick with the guidelines and place the EditButton on the right side of the Navbar

Comment: @amandir i have an add button to the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you mean swiping on cell you need delete option.

If so you can try this code:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //perform delete operation

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have all of the delegates implemented below

```
tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:
tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:
tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath
```

:

Comment: Yes, I implemented, also connected data source and delegate, not working

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
//delete code here
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
```

once you write above method in your delegate you will be able to use swipe gestures.... and in this method you will handle the subsequent actions that you want to perform.

thanks.....

Comment: No..the left swipe is not bring detected at all.

Comment: UISwipeGestureRecognizer *tempGestureRecognizer = [[self.tableView gestureRecognizers] objectAtIndex:2];
tempGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft|UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;